# how can I create an mobile application having mouse cursor, which moves on screen with buttons in j2me?

Tags: java-me, mouse-cursor

i want to use a cursor in my j2me application as it is being used by different web browse in 
cell phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take an image of pointer and the use pointer pressed and pointer released  method which will give u the cordinates which pointer had pointer.For using this pointer presse method you have to extend  Game canvas or Canvas class into your class.

```
example:--

public class  Example extends GameCanvas {

public Example()
    {
        super(false);
    }
 public void keyPressed(int keycode)
    {
    }
protected void pointerPressed(int X,int Y) 
   {
   }
protected void pointerDrageed(int X,int Y) 
   {
   }
protected void pointerReleased(int X,int Y) 
   {
   }
```

By using above methods i think you can get the solution of your problem.